Rav Hirsch on the Torah in German
Where can I get Rav Hirsch's commentary on the Torah in German in the USA?

https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Hirsch%2C%20Samson%20Raphael%2C%201808%2D1888

Also here: https://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/6611035
